# how can i python dictionary duplication values and rebuild

Tags: python, dictionary

i have problem in python dictionary.

i want to dictionary

[As is]

```
{'level_1_name': 'asset', 'level_2_name': 'search', 'usage_permission': 'CREATE'}
{'level_1_name': 'asset', 'level_2_name': 'search', 'usage_permission': 'READ'}
{'level_1_name': 'asset', 'level_2_name': 'search', 'usage_permission': 'EDIT'}
{'level_1_name': 'server', 'level_2_name': 'keysearch', 'usage_permission': 'CREATE'}
{'level_1_name': 'server', 'level_2_name': 'keysearch', 'usage_permission': 'DELETE'}
```

[To be]

```
{'level_1_name': 'asset', 'level_2_name': 'search', 'usage_permission': ['CREATE', 'READ', 'EDIT']}
{'level_1_name': 'server', 'level_2_name': 'keysearch', 'usage_permission': ['CREATE', 'DELETE']}
```

What can i do?
plese help me..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a simple iteration.

**Ex:**

```
data = [{'level_1_name': 'asset', 'level_2_name': 'search', 'usage_permission': 'CREATE'},
{'level_1_name': 'asset', 'level_2_name': 'search', 'usage_permission': 'READ'},
{'level_1_name': 'asset', 'level_2_name': 'search', 'usage_permission': 'EDIT'},
{'level_1_name': 'server', 'level_2_name': 'keysearch', 'usage_permission': 'CREATE'},
{'level_1_name': 'server', 'level_2_name': 'keysearch', 'usage_permission': 'DELETE'}]
result = {}
for i in data:
    if i['level_1_name'] not in result:
        result[i['level_1_name']] = {'usage_permission': [i.pop('usage_permission')], **i }
    else:
        result[i['level_1_name']]['usage_permission'].append(i['usage_permission'])
    
print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
{'asset': {'level_1_name': 'asset',
           'level_2_name': 'search',
           'usage_permission': ['CREATE', 'READ', 'EDIT']},
 'server': {'level_1_name': 'server',
            'level_2_name': 'keysearch',
            'usage_permission': ['CREATE', 'DELETE']}}
```

Comment: can you explain about the usage of ```**i``` here?

Comment: That is object unpacking in python